# How to decode special characters in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting following response from a HTTP request:-

```
\u0001\u0010\u0001\u001a\b39f6d16e\u001a\b28a256ac\u001a\b4b863252\u001a\b76d9f029\u001a\bf08c7032\u001a\b505daa3b\u001a\b0fce12a0\u001a\babfb17d5\u001a\b867e754d\u001a\b557b3f8e\u001a\b0176eea0\u001a\be515e30a\u001a\b2528ffd3\u001a\b78fc9d5b\u001a\ba7de4a4d\u001a\b09bb1da7\u001a\b623e1f11\u001a\b2083caa6\u001a\bd57998b1\u001a\b9ac21169\u001a\b4841a319\u001a\b136fa811\u001a\ba3ea6f2a\u001a\b6a1763ff\u001a\b0659b490\u001a\b24c5bf0d\u001a\bf4f63823\u001a\bc8d71292\u001a\b219c6721\u001a\b3f0bc0d3\u001a\b96b3a20f\u001a\b92d3cc0d\u001a\b9b1f4f81\u001a\b782e39ff\u001a\b00bb4a52\u001a\b6f507e1e\u001a\bab02a2a2\u001a\b3f40b831\u001a\bc2319c97\u001a\b2f4c716f\u001a\b74db656c\u001a\bdc79701d\u001a\b282bd77d\u001a\b495b2dac\u001a\b37be6ed5\
```

Can somebody know what type of encoding it is and how to decode it in readable format in C# ?

Comment: Unicode. Show more code please how you retrieve that string.

Comment: Please insert the code how you get the HTTP request.

Comment: It looks like an odd attempt to encode binary data by treating it as text and using text escapes, what should it actually represent?

Comment: its unicode

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/index.htm

Comment: Where is this string coming from? If this is output from a debugger, be aware that it has taken care of changing the data to a C#-escaped string. In that case you don't have an encoding issue -- the data is just not human readable, but a sequence of 4-byte hexstrings (which do not represent code points) separated by control characters. You'll need to know who's outputting this data and why before you can take a stab at interpreting it. Does the HTTP response have a `Content-Type`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Content-Type is application/octet-stream

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is the equivalent of the server saying "I don't know what this is, nobody told me". You'll need to ask whoever is providing that content what this is and what you're supposed to do with it, it's not possible to say out of context.